# Cerrar aplicación de forma automática W10

Tags: windows10

¿Cómo puedo cerrar una aplicación de forma automática, si la misma NO está siendo utilizada por el usario en un S.O windows10?

Comment: ¿De manera remota? ¿Es un programa que tú hiciste? ¿es un programa de terceros? Podrías aclarar un poco más

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es un programa de un tercero, abres el software trabajas en él y después de determinado tiempo vuelves a querer trabajar en el mismo y se bloquea apareciendo el mensaje "No Responde" teniendo que cerrarlo forzosamente mediante el adiminstrador de tareas para ello quiero saber si existe alguna manera de poder cerrar la aplicación de forma automática después de determinado tiempo sin estar usándola.